# Sync database for Android app

Tags: android, google-drive-api, dropbox-api, data-synchronization

I'm going to make app for Android which need to synchronize database between other devices.
Instead of making server to handle this I would  like to use already made product.

I have found that [Dropbox datastore](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/android) will probably do what I need. However I would like to use something from Google (no need to have account on Dropbox).

On Google sites I have found: [NDB Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) and [DB Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/). I have also got [NDB vs DB Datastore](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic) doc. But I don't really get what's the main difference beetwen them.

So, if I understand this correctly Dropbox makes datastores for each users separatly where I don't have acces to datas, but Google provides datastores where I have access to every data from users datastore.

Can anyone, in a simple way, explain what is the main difference between NDB and DB and correct if I'm wrong with my last statement.

Comment: I believe both NDB Datastore and DB Datastore are storage solutions for Google App Engine apps. Are you planning to run your own web service in GAE? An advantage to using Dropbox is that your clients can talk directly to Dropbox without having to go through server-side code that you have to write and maintain.

Comment: From the link: `In case you wondered, despite the different APIs, NDB and the old ext.db package write exactly the same data to the Datastore. That means you don’t have to do any conversion to your datastore, and you can happily mix and match NDB and ext.db code, as long as the schema you use is equivalent. ` . So they are just different APIs for the same data.

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/android-drive-sync/source/browse/Andriod/src/com/example/android/cloudnotes/service/DriveSyncService.java

i guess this should help!!

this is drive sync service by google